# How use for loop for chosen elements from nested lists

Tags: python-3.x

I want to choose some elements from nested lists and use them inside 'for' loop.

I have taken elements needed from each nested list and created a new list. Then I used 'for' loop. However I wonder if there is more firct and faster option to do that.

```
list = [['name_1', 0, 0, 0], ['name_2', 0, 0, 0], ['name_3', 0, 0, 0]]
```

I have tried

```
new_list = [list[0][0], list[1][0], list[2][0]]
for element in new_list:
    print(element)
```

Is it possible to create 'for' loop without creating a separate list for 'name' elements?

Just want to be more specific: 
1. I don't want to create ANY new list a all. 2. If the code is:

`new_list = [list[0][0], list[1][0], list[2][0]]
for element in new_list: #in this line I want 'element to be name_1, name_2 and name_3, so I want to loop over 'name' elements... print(element)`

Answer (score 1):

using list comprehension,

```
llist = [['name_1', 0, 0, 0], ['name_2', 0, 0, 0], ['name_3', 0, 0, 0]]
newlist = [x[0] for x in llist]

print(newlist) # ['name_1', 'name_2', 'name_3']
```

You can iterate the new_list and print the names as needed,

```
for name in newlist:
    print(name)
```

If you don't want to create a new list for this purpose, you can do this,

```
llist = [['name_1', 0, 0, 0], ['name_2', 0, 0, 0], ['name_3', 0, 0, 0]]

for name in [x[0] for x in llist]:
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the nested elements directly from the `for` loop:

```
inputlist = [['name_1', 0, 0, 0], ['name_2', 0, 0, 0], ['name_3', 0, 0, 0]]

for element in inputlist:
    print(element[0])
```

Output:

```
name_1
name_2
name_3
```